# iOS CAKeyFrameAnimation Rotate

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-animation, calayer, cakeyframeanimation

I have written this `CAKEyFrameAnimaton` to rotate a `CALayer` on it's X-axis. But it is not rotating. What am I doing wrong here?

```
CAKeyframeAnimation *topFoldAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.x"];
topFoldAnimation.duration             = 15;
topFoldAnimation.repeatCount          = 1;
topFoldAnimation.removedOnCompletion  = NO;
topFoldAnimation.autoreverses         = NO;
topFoldAnimation.fillMode             = kCAFillModeForwards;

CATransform3D tTrans                  = CATransform3DIdentity;
tTrans.m34                            = -1/900;

topFoldAnimation.values               = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                        [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DRotate(tTrans,DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(0),1,0,0)],
                                        [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DRotate(tTrans,DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(-30),1,0,0)],
                                        [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DRotate(tTrans,DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(-60),1,0,0)],
                                        [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DRotate(tTrans,DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(-90),1,0,0)],
                                           nil];
topFoldAnimation.keyTimes             = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                          [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.00], 
                                          [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.25],
                                          [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.50],
                                          [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.00],
                                           nil];
topFoldAnimation.timingFunctions      = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                         [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear], 
                                         [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear],
                                         [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear],
                                         [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear],
                                           nil];
[[backgroundAnimationLayer.sublayers objectAtIndex:1] addAnimation:topFoldAnimation forKey:@"transform.rotation.x"];
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your animation `keyPath` is wrong, it should be just `transform` and not `transform.rotation.x`.

Also, you'll end up with `0` in `tTrans.m34` because you're using integer division. It should probably be `-1.0/900`.

Comment: yes I am assigning m34 to get a 2.5D perspective. and why subLayer? If I apply it to the layer, all the sublayers should get that transform, right?

Comment: Right, I somehow assumed that `m34` only had an effect for `subLayerTransform` because I've always used it this way but that doesn't seem to be the case. Still, you're effectively assigning 0 here which definitely won't have the desired effect.